# Draggable image from Jquery is getting dragged to the whole page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, html

I am using [Jquery Draggable code from this link](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

I am trying to drag an image within a DIV but it is getting dragged to the whole page.
My code is as follows

```
<div>
     <span class="move" id="draggable">
          <img src="cropped/image_name.jpg"/>
     </span>
</div>
```

I do not want this image to be draggable outside of the DIV. Rest of the code is working perfecrly. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the documentation? They have an example for constraining the movement http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Give the div a width and height? It will take up 100% unless set.

Comment: @andrew-buchan, 100% width, and `auto` (i.e. as needed) height are the defaults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [containment option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)

```
$('#draggable img').draggable({
    containment: $('#draggable').parent()
})
```

Comment: So quick reply. I am really thankful to you. I didn't understand the given documentation on jquery draggable portal meant for my doubt only. I need to put more concentration. But anyway this code is working like charm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Lsc3r/1

```
 $("#draggable img ").draggable({ containment: "#div1" });
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is also working fine. Thank you so much for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

you don't want it to be visible outside the parent element???

```
overflow:hidden
```